# How to use PhoneGap the right way

Tags: cordova

So I have successfully created and released a PhoneGap app for Android. I think. The thing is, I don't think I understand PhoneGap, and I suspect I do it "wrong".

The app in its entirety has been created inside Eclipse. When I Google PhoneGap, I often find references to command line prompts and stuff, which I do none of. This confuses me.

My Eclipse project looks like this:

[image]

Does this look "right"? My biggest concern is that that I don't use the stuff you install with node.js which http://phonegap.com/install/ talks about. I'll be forever thankful if someone could explain to me how this all works.

Comment: How you install it? tell me more details about it.

Comment: Where did you get the /assets/www content from? YOur best bet is to read the developer > docs at phonegap.com for the "right way."